# Tiebreaker for maximum value in pandas row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The sample of the dataset I am working on:

```
import pandas as pd
# List of Tuples
matrix = [(1, 0.3, 0, 0.7, 30, 0, 50),
          (2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 20, 50, 30),
          (3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 30, 20, 30),
          (4, 0.7, 0, 0.3, 100, 0, 40),
          (5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 50, 30, 80)
          ]
# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=["id", "terror", "drama", "action", "val_terror", "val_drama", "val_action"])
```

[image]

My goal is to create a column referring to the highest value of a genre for each customer (considering only the first three columns at first). For example, in the first row the value for action wins.

But in the second row, we have a tie. Following the df.max(axis=1) function, we will get the first value that it observes as the maximum (which would be for terror). In those cases where there is a tie, I would like to receive the genre with the highest value, for example, in the second row it would be val_drama. Something like:

[image]

I thought of separating the dataframes into id's that have equal values ​​and applying the max(axis=1) on both dataframes and then joining. But I'm not succeeding in this task.

Comment: his site is best used once you have a specific problem that you can't figure out around code that you are writing. Your question, instead, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Can someone point me towards a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `numpy.where`.
In the first two lines I create two subsets just for easier referencing.
Then I use numpy.where to check whether a rows maximum occurs more than once. If yes, I check the other three columns.

```
import numpy as np
ss1 = df[["terror", "drama", "action"]]
ss2 = df[["val_terror", "val_drama", "val_action"]]
df["largest_score"] = np.where(ss1.eq(ss1.max(axis=1), axis=0).sum(axis=1) > 1,
                               ss2.idxmax(axis=1).str.replace("val_", ""),
                               ss1.idxmax(axis=1))
```

Comment: The second condition compares the entire list of ss2, which can result in a problem. For example, for id = 5 if we had val_terror > val_action. The code above would put 'terror' as the largest_score, but 'terror' is not the tiebreaker. Is there any way to compare only the values ​​that have a tie? Thanks for the answer above.